# Routing API ignores closed roads

Tags: here-api

I'm testing the routing API and I'm wondering why it creates routes through closed roads.

There is my request: https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=geo!50.01568168937738,20.901489257812504&waypoint1=geo!50.0155162303763,20.879259109497074&apiKey=API-KEY-HERE&mode=balanced%3Bcar&alternatives=0

```
{
  "response": {
    "metaInfo": {
      "timestamp": "2020-03-31T16:54:22Z",
      "mapVersion": "8.30.107.151",
      "moduleVersion": "7.2.202013-6746",
      "interfaceVersion": "2.6.76",
      "availableMapVersion": [
        "8.30.107.151"
      ]
    },
    "route": [
      {
        "waypoint": [
          {
            "linkId": "-985497829",
            "mappedPosition": {
              "latitude": 50.0160635,
              "longitude": 20.9021437
            },
            "originalPosition": {
              "latitude": 50.0156817,
              "longitude": 20.9014893
            },
            "type": "stopOver",
            "spot": 1,
            "sideOfStreet": "right",
            "mappedRoadName": "ulica Wędkarska",
            "label": "ulica Wędkarska",
            "shapeIndex": 0,
            "source": "user"
          },
          {
            "linkId": "-1052271133",
            "mappedPosition": {
              "latitude": 50.0154679,
              "longitude": 20.8792651
            },
            "originalPosition": {
              "latitude": 50.0155162,
              "longitude": 20.8792591
            },
            "type": "stopOver",
            "spot": 0.6372549,
            "sideOfStreet": "right",
            "mappedRoadName": "Ostrów",
            "label": "Ostrów",
            "shapeIndex": 29,
            "source": "user"
          }
        ],
        "mode": {
          "type": "balanced",
          "transportModes": [
            "car"
          ],
          "trafficMode": "disabled",
          "feature": []
        },
        "leg": [
          {
            "start": {
              "linkId": "-985497829",
              "mappedPosition": {
                "latitude": 50.0160635,
                "longitude": 20.9021437
              },
              "originalPosition": {
                "latitude": 50.0156817,
                "longitude": 20.9014893
              },
              "type": "stopOver",
              "spot": 1,
              "sideOfStreet": "right",
              "mappedRoadName": "ulica Wędkarska",
              "label": "ulica Wędkarska",
              "shapeIndex": 0,
              "source": "user"
            },
            "end": {
              "linkId": "-1052271133",
              "mappedPosition": {
                "latitude": 50.0154679,
                "longitude": 20.8792651
              },
              "originalPosition": {
                "latitude": 50.0155162,
                "longitude": 20.8792591
              },
              "type": "stopOver",
              "spot": 0.6372549,
              "sideOfStreet": "right",
              "mappedRoadName": "Ostrów",
              "label": "Ostrów",
              "shapeIndex": 29,
              "source": "user"
            },
            "length": 2383,
            "travelTime": 312,
            "maneuver": [
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 50.0160635,
                  "longitude": 20.9021437
                },
                "instruction": "Head <span class=\"heading\">east</span> on <span class=\"street\">ulica Wędkarska</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">153 m</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 24,
                "length": 153,
                "id": "M1",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 50.0159132,
                  "longitude": 20.9040749
                },
                "instruction": "Turn <span class=\"direction\">right</span> onto <span class=\"next-street\">ulica Wędkarska</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">108 m</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 18,
                "length": 108,
                "id": "M2",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 50.0150228,
                  "longitude": 20.904547
                },
                "instruction": "Turn <span class=\"direction\">right</span> onto <span class=\"next-street\">ulica Dunajcowa</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">374 m</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 55,
                "length": 374,
                "id": "M3",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 50.0127375,
                  "longitude": 20.9007919
                },
                "instruction": "Turn <span class=\"direction\">slightly right</span> onto <span class=\"next-street\">ulica Do Promu</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">75 m</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 18,
                "length": 75,
                "id": "M4",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 50.0126946,
                  "longitude": 20.8997512
                },
                "instruction": "Turn <span class=\"direction\">left</span> onto <span class=\"next-street\">ulica Do Promu</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">249 m</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 41,
                "length": 249,
                "id": "M5",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 50.0111175,
                  "longitude": 20.897305
                },
                "instruction": "Turn <span class=\"direction\">right</span> onto <span class=\"next-street\">ulica Wincentego Witosa</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">717 m</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 92,
                "length": 717,
                "id": "M6",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 50.0145936,
                  "longitude": 20.8889151
                },
                "instruction": "Continue on <span class=\"next-street\">Ostrów</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">707 m</span>.</span>",
                "travelTime": 64,
                "length": 707,
                "id": "M7",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              },
              {
                "position": {
                  "latitude": 50.0154679,
                  "longitude": 20.8792651
                },
                "instruction": "Arrive at <span class=\"street\">Ostrów</span>. Your destination is on the right.",
                "travelTime": 0,
                "length": 0,
                "id": "M8",
                "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "summary": {
          "distance": 2383,
          "trafficTime": 312,
          "baseTime": 312,
          "flags": [
            "builtUpArea"
          ],
          "text": "The trip takes <span class=\"length\">2.4 km</span> and <span class=\"time\">5 mins</span>.",
          "travelTime": 312,
          "_type": "RouteSummaryType"
        }
      }
    ],
    "language": "en-us"
  }
}
```

The proposed route looks like that:
[route through the closed bride](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDHcP.png).

The road closure info is available in the map. I've checked that in the Map Creator. Here WeGo map also knows about this and suggest an alternative route: 
[the valid route from Here WeGo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lo5e.png).

Is there something wrong with my request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using following combinations for mode in your rest call. The Routing API v7 supports the following valid parameter combinations for routing modes.

```
Traffic-enabled:

mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled

Traffic not enabled:

mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled
mode=shortest;car
```

Also refer : https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/routing-mode-parameter-combinations.html

Please connect even if this doesn't result to what you are expecting the output to be

Comment: It works fine when I use "traffic:enabled" mode. Anyway with "traffic:disabled" it creates routes through the closed road. The car/truck or fastest/shortest modes does not change anything in this case.

Is it an expected behavior that it ignores road closures when the traffic mode is disabled?